# Efficient array creation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am trying to create a three dimensional array, Tusing numpy defined as follows:

T_{i, j, k} = \delta_{i, k} - \delta{j, k}

where \delta_{i, j} is the Kronecker delta function (1 when i=j and 0 otherwise). I am wondering what the most efficient way to do this using numpy. I can create two three dimensional arrays using for loops and subtract them. But I suspect there is a quicker and more idiomatic method. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent to delta is `eye` in numpy:

```
delta = numpy.eye(5)
T = delta[:,None,:] - delta[None,:,:]
```

The `None` creates a ‹virtual› dimension (doesn't take any additional memory) used for broadcasting in numpy.

Comment: Awesome! Just so I can better understand this. Suppose I just wanted to create a three dimensional array X defined by X_{i, j, k} = X_{i, k} for all j. The first term in the above does not seem to do that as the first dimension must have length. How would I do that?

Comment: @gzc yes I think there is a typo. What we want is delta[:, None, :] - delta[None, :, :]